# Martingale property on a $\sigma$-algebra generated by intervals

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the unit interval $I=[0,1]$ equipped with the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$ and the Lesbesgue measure $\lambda$. Now let $f$ be an integrable function on $I$ and define for $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$ f_n(x) = 2^n \int_{(k-1)2^{-n}}^{k2^{-n}} f(y) dy, \quad (k-1)2^{-n} \leq x < k2^{-n}. $$
Finally define $\mathcal{F}_n$ as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the intervals of the form $\left[(k-1)2^{-n},k2^{-n}\right)$, $1 \leq k \leq 2^n$. The set of all intervals of these form we denote by $A_n$.

I now want to prove that $(f_n)_n$ is a martingale ($\mathbb{E}[f_n | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = f_{n-1}$). I already proved that $\mathcal{F}_n$ is in fact a filtration as each interval in $A_n$ can be written as the union of two intervals in $A_{n+1}$ hence the $\sigma$-algebra is increasing.

I then tried to prove that $f_n$ is a martingale by using the following general property: if we divide $[0,1]$ into intervals $\left[\frac{(j-1)}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right)$ with $j =1,2,\ldots,n$ and denote $\mathcal{G}_n$ as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by those intervals. We can write the conditional expectation for a Borel measurable $X$ as
$$ \mathbb{E}  [X | \mathcal{G}_n ](\omega) = n \int_\frac{(j-1)}{n}^\frac{j}{n} X(s) \lambda(ds) \text{ when $\omega \in \left[\frac{(j-1)}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right)$}$$
But I think applying this does not work in my case as I suppose that $k$ is not a natural number. However if I do suppose this works I guess I get for $\omega \in I$
$$\mathbb{E} [ f_n | \mathcal{F}_{n-1} ](\omega) =  2^{n-1} \int_{(i-1)2^{-(n-1)}}^{i2^{-(n-1)}} f_n(s) \lambda(ds) \text{ when $\omega \in \left[(i-1)2^{-(n-1)},i2^{-(n-1)}\right)$}$$
And I now tried applying Fubini's theorem but still I don't get the desired $f_{n-1}$. Is there any other way this could be proven? I'll be glad with any help or even small hints. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Apply the general property to $f$, not to $f_n$. I'm pretty sure $k$ takes integer values in your definition of $f_n$, so the general property applies with $X=f$. By comparing the definition of $f_n$ to the integral in the general property, you can see $f_n=E(f|\mathcal G_{2^n})$. But $\mathcal G_{2^n}=\mathcal F_n$, so $f_n=E(f|\mathcal F_n)$.

Comment: I did not think of such a trick! My many thanks!